# What is The Aperture Function

Tags: optics

I am trying to answer some pre lab questions. The term aperture function is used in these questions and I am wondering what it means?

Comment: if you don't get an answer here (you might not) try www.physicsforums.com

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. What is the context in which this term is used? Can you post an image of the text?

Comment: Actually, rather than an image of a text that @sammygerbil suggested, it's be far better to actually type the pre-lab text itself into the post (because (a) it'd be legible and (b) it'd be searchable for future users).

Answer (score 1):

The aperture function is probably a function that describes the transmission of the aperture as a function of position in the aperture plane.

For example, a simple round aperture with radius $r$ would have an aperture function like

$$T(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,&x^2+y^2<r^2\\
0,&x^2+y^2\ge r^2
\end{cases}$$